# Separar texto luego de un espacio, luego de otro caracter específico

Tags: excel, macos, microsoft-office

Necesito generar una fórmula de Excel para separar un texto de una dirección, tengo un libro de 2000 líneas que van de esta forma

> Cr.27C  #91-155 Alfonzo Bonilla Aragon

alguien sabe como separar la dirección

> Cr.27C  #91-155

del nombre

> Alfonzo Bonilla Aragon

creo que la clave esta en el ultimo número de la dirección pero no se como llamarlo.

algunos datos

```
CALLE 52 #1D2-19 SALOMIA
Cra.67 #11B-27 piso 2 el limonar
Cra.14 #4-56 san cayetano
Cra.29 #26b-114 el jardin
CALLE 79 #T 103-03  LOS NARANJOS
Cra.4C #34-31  PORVENIR
Calle 14 #43-26 guabal
CALLE 1 C #74-16  PRADOS DEL SUR
```

como se puede ver, después del último dato de la dirección siempre va una palabra que no lleva números

Comment: ¿Todos los registros tienen el mismo patron de #11-111 es decir despues de # van dos digitos y despues un guion y tres digitos?

Comment: Sería genial que muestres varios ejemplos, y no solo uno

Comment: @M.Gress los números pueden variar

Comment: Creo que te puede ayudar la información del siguiente link https://exceltotal.com/separar-una-cadena-de-texto/

Comment: @Nikolas parecería, por los datos que publicaste, que podrías buscar la posición del primer `#`, luego el primer `-` desde ahí, y tomar el texto desde el primer espacio luego de eso... ¿Te parece que podría aplicarse a tus valores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viendo tus datos, parecería viable buscar el primer espacio, luego del primer `"-"`, luego del primer `"#"` encontrado en el texto.

Si la celda donde está la primer dirección es `A2`, vayamos por pasos:

1. Encontremos la posición del primer `#`

   ```
   =HALLAR("#";A2)
   ```

   > Nota: uso `;` como separador de parámetros, quizás uses `,` y tengas que cambiarlo.

2. Encontremos la posición del primer `-` que se encuentra después de la posición del `"#"`

   ```
   =HALLAR("-";A2;  <posición_que_obtuvimos_en_1>  )
   ```

   o sea,

   ```
   =HALLAR("-";A2; HALLAR("#";A2) )
   ```

3. Encontremos la posición del primer `" "` desde la posición anterior

   ```
   =HALLAR(" ";A2;  <posición_que_obtuvimos_en_2>  )
   ```

   o sea,

   ```
   =HALLAR(" ";A2; HALLAR("-";A2;HALLAR("#";A2)) )
   ```

   En realidad, ahora deberíamos sumarle 1 a la posición para que lo tome *después* del espacio, pero esperemos al último punto.

4. Ya tenemos la posición, ahora obtenemos el texto desde esa posición

   ```
   =EXTRAE(A2;  <posición_que_obtuvimos_en_3>  ;LARGO(A2))
   ```

   o sea,

   ```
   =EXTRAE(A2; HALLAR(" ";A2;HALLAR("-";A2;HALLAR("#";A2))) ;LARGO(A2))
   ```

5. Un detalle, como algunos de tus valores tienen más de un espacio separando la dirección, usamos ESPACIOS() para eliminarlos.

   ```
   =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A2;HALLAR(" ";A2;HALLAR("-";A2;HALLAR("#";A2)));LARGO(A2)))
   ```

---

#### Fórmula

```
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    |                   A                    |                                         B                                         |
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Direcciones                            | Valor buscado                                                                     |
|  2 | Cr.27C  #91-155 Alfonzo Bonilla Aragon | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A2;HALLAR(" ";A2;HALLAR("-";A2;HALLAR("#";A2)));LARGO(A2)))      |
|  3 | CALLE 52 #1D2-19 SALOMIA               | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A3;HALLAR(" ";A3;HALLAR("-";A3;HALLAR("#";A3)));LARGO(A3)))      |
|  4 | Cra.67 #11B-27 piso 2 el limonar       | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A4;HALLAR(" ";A4;HALLAR("-";A4;HALLAR("#";A4)));LARGO(A4)))      |
|  5 | Cra.14 #4-56 san cayetano              | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A5;HALLAR(" ";A5;HALLAR("-";A5;HALLAR("#";A5)));LARGO(A5)))      |
|  6 | Cra.29 #26b-114 el jardin              | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A6;HALLAR(" ";A6;HALLAR("-";A6;HALLAR("#";A6)));LARGO(A6)))      |
|  7 | CALLE 79 #T 103-03  LOS NARANJOS       | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A7;HALLAR(" ";A7;HALLAR("-";A7;HALLAR("#";A7)));LARGO(A7)))      |
|  8 | Cra.4C #34-31  PORVENIR                | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A8;HALLAR(" ";A8;HALLAR("-";A8;HALLAR("#";A8)));LARGO(A8)))      |
|  9 | Calle 14 #43-26 guabal                 | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A9;HALLAR(" ";A9;HALLAR("-";A9;HALLAR("#";A9)));LARGO(A9)))      |
| 10 | CALLE 1 C #74-16  PRADOS DEL SUR       | =ESPACIOS(EXTRAE(A10;HALLAR(" ";A10;HALLAR("-";A10;HALLAR("#";A10)));LARGO(A10))) |
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Resultado

[image: Captura de Excel]

Comment: perfecto, muchisimas gracias